# Result of the pushforward of a line bundle by a many-to-one map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Take $n$ copies of a topological space $M$, and consider this as a single (disconnected) topological space $X$. Let $f:X\to M$ be an $n$-to-1 map that maps the $n$ copies, via separate identity maps, onto a single copy $M$.

Now consider the pushforward or direct image map $f_*$. Suppose we place a different line bundle $L_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) on each copy of $M$, and we map this by the pushforward to give an object $V$ on $M$.

My question is whether the resulting object $V$ is a direct sum of the line bundles $L_i$, i.e. whether $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n L_i$, or if the result is a more general vector bundle (or perhaps it is not a vector bundle at all).

Comment: I think your $M$s and $X$s are a little flipped around in the first line?

Comment: @KReiser Thanks very much! I've corrected it.

Comment: Hint: for an open set $U \subset M$, what is $f^{-1}(U)$? What does that tell you about the pushforward sheaf?

Comment: @Nefertiti Thanks for the comment. I know that $f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$, where the $U_i$ are the $n$ copies of $U$ from the $n$ copies of $M$, and that by the definition of the pushforward map, for the sheaf $V$ resulting from the pushforward of a sheaf $F$ it is the case that $V(U)=F(f^{-1}(U))=F(\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i)$. But I suppose I can't see whether this means $V$ is a line bundle sum or a more general vector bundle.

Comment: Try to construct a map between the pushforward sheaf and the vector bundle $\oplus_i L_i$ on $M$. Show it is an isomorphism on each open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above by Nefertiti, we can study, given $U \subset M$, what is $f^{-1}(U)$ and what that tells about the pushforward sheaf $V$. Well $f^{-1}(U) = \coprod_i U_i$, where $U_i$ are disjoint copies of $U$ in the various disjoint copies of $M$. So by sheaf properties,
$$
V(U) = F(f^{-1}(U)) =
\bigoplus_i F(U_i) =
 \bigoplus_i L_i(U_i).
$$
This holds for any open set so the pushforward sheaf $V$ is the direct sum of the $L_i$.